# Passing a method to EventListenerList "add" method

Tags: dart

I want to do something like the following:

```
void handleClick(){
    //do stuff
}

void addHandlerToButton(){
    window.document.query('#somebutton').on.click.add(handleClick);
}
```

Dart editor's static checking reports `'() -> void' is not assignable to 'EventListener'`

I have a feeling I'm missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click handlers gets the click event passed as a argument (so you for example can get the screen coordiantes, target element etc.). So your handler method signature must be

```
void handleClick(Event event){
    // do stuff with event
}
```

The error you are reciving is actually telling you that (although in a cryptic way):

> '() -> void' is not assignable to 'EventListener'

Here **EventListener** is basically any function type with signature **void handle(Event event)** so the function you add with **on.click.add** must match this signature.

Comment: I knew once I saw the answer I'd smack myself.  Thanks again, Lars.